# How to write a divide & conquer algorithm for finding the longest consecutive chain of numbers in an array

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

For example, we have an array `[2,3,4,6,8,9,10,11]`

The result must be `8, 9, 10, 11` because they are already sorted in increasing order and are consecutive integers. So I have to write a divide & conquer algorithm which finds out the longest `A[i:j]` sequence from `A[1:n]` that is sorted in increasing order.

I'm kind of confused about how to get started. Can someone help out here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Consider a function `fn(arr, l, r)`, which returns a tuple containing:

1. length of the longest sorted sub-array between indexes `[l,r]`
2. length of the longest sorted sub-array between indexes `[l,r]` that ends at index `r`

The algorithm would be:

1. Calculate mid-point `mid = (l+r)/2`
2. Recursively call `left = fn(arr, l, mid)` and `right = fn(arr, mid+1, r)`, where `left` and `right` are tuples as described above
3. Temporary value `val1 = max(left[0], right[0])`
4. Calculate length of longest sorted subarray for right half (between `[mid+1, r]`) that starts at `mid+1`. Let this length be `l1`
5. Similarly, calculate length of longest sorted subarray for right half (between `[mid+1, r]`) that ends at `r`. Let this length be `l2`
6. `val2 = max(ans, left[1] + l1)`
7. Answer for this subarray `ans = max(val1, val2)`
8. Return tuple `(ans, l2)`

Comment: I didn't get the 4th and 5th steps. Should it be both for the right halves? And how is it  `mid+1`? Don't we have to start from the start of the array i.e. with `l`? @AbhinavMathur